# Why are my boids jittery?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to make a scene with fighters using boids. They move around and turn, and from a distance it looks alright, but when I look closer, they are moving irregularly and turning a little in random directions when they don't need to. When I looked online, people seem to take this jittering for granted, but I'd rather they moved smoothly. What can I do about it?

More information at Rich Sedman's request:
The Boid brain has four rules in this order
follow leader
seperate
avoid collision(boids is checked)
avoid collision(deflectors is checked.)
It follows a deflector object as a leader, so that it moves toward it without hitting it. Everything works fine except their movement is jittery.
a recording of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkMqv.jpg

Comment: If i recall correctly, the jittering usually comes as a side effect of the cohesion rule (moving towards center of mass of nearby boids). You could try just disabling that one, or reducing its strength

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in this question for a meaningful answer without someone taking considerable time to try and guess the poster's situation and replicate something similar. Consider updating the question to include sufficient detail as to how your boids are configured to demonstrate the jittering you're referring to.

Comment: I agree with @Rich.  Upload a sample dot blend file can help.

Comment: I’ve tried to replicate that and don’t see anything I could describe as ‘jittering’. Can you post an animated gif showing what you’re seeing?

Comment: Thanks for the extra info - it looks like the problem is the rapid changes it the direction each boid is facing - presumably as it switches target as it tried to follow the rules.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to replicate the jittering... did you change any other boid settings? Can you either share your Blend file or replicate the setup in a fresh blend file and share that?